# What's wrong with my gear shifter?

Tags: gears, shifter

The mechanism inside one of my gear shifters is a bit skewiff and I can't lock the cover on properly. Any idea what the problem is? Pictures of the dodgy one and the ok one for comparison with the cover off and then on.

[image: shifter]

[image: shifter]

[image: shifter]

[image: shifter]

I think a part may be missing from the dodgy one?

Dodgy one:

[image: shifter]

OK one (with an extra cog?):

[image: shifter]

Comment: Hard to distinguish how each picture relates to the others. I can't figure out what you mean by a part missing or an extra cog being present. The first picture seems to show a coil spring that is mispositioned. Do you know what model the shifters are?

Comment: Pic 1 and 2 are the same, as are 4 and 5

Comment: What is the model of the shifter? Have you tried looking up its schematics on the net?

Comment: Note left and right are mirrors, but not identical due to the number of detents.  So the right/rear shifter may be quite different on the inside.

Comment: While I totally owould try and fix these, if there's a part broken/snapped its easier to just replace the whole mech.  Shifters are reasonably cheap.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be an EZ-Fire type shifter.  Shimano or copy-cat. One model number is ST-EF29.  That spring is misaligned and you'll need to get that seated properly. Then I suggest a good dousing with WD-40 or equivalent and exercising the shifter repeatedly. You may need to use a toothpick or the like to scrape out old grease and dirt.  After cleaning, follow up with some sort of wet lube and work the shifters again. I've linked to a video showing some work being done on a very similar shifter to yours. 
Typically I don't find these types of shifters "broken" but rather gummed up or pieces disconnected like your spring. It's common for the junction to the gear indicator to be disconnected and/ or the little plastic connection broken. This doesn't affect the actual shifting just the gear indicator.
You have a good chance of getting this working sans the "dodginess."

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like the spring 'jumped' out, occupying space and causing the nut on the top to unscrew itself. Not sure, i'm not a bike mechanic but maybe try unscrewing the nut, remove the washer and carefully place the spring back in and reassemble everything back. it *MIGHT* work, but don't trust me that much. I'm just suggesting you to try it, we might help you better if you provide us the **model** of the shifter because we might able to find the blueprint of the shifter.